# What is the difference between Shannon entropy and saying that tossing a 6-sided die 100 times has more than 256-bit entropy?

Tags: entropy

I'm confused.

I thought that tossing a 6-sided die 100 times had a greater than 256-bit entropy because $6^{99} < 2^{256} < 6^{100}$. (A similar concept appeared in [this XKCD comic](https://xkcd.com/936/), where choosing four random words from a dictionary of presumably 2048 words has a 44-bit entropy, presumably because $2048^4 = 2^{44}$.)

On the other hand, the **Shannon entropy** of a 6-sided die tossed 100 times is $-6 × 1/6 × \log_2(1/6) = 2.5849625007$ bits. (According to the comments by Sakamaki Izayoi to [my other question](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/96370/a-simple-question-about-entropy-and-random-data).)

Are these two different concepts of "entropy" entirely? If so, what's the difference and if not, what am I missing?

I read [this thread](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/21143/confused-about-password-entropy) but I'm still confused.

Comment: log2(6^100) = log2(6)*100

Comment: Can someone explain what the point of this formula is? -6*1/6 == -1. -1*log(1/6) = log(6). Under what circumstances are the terms different?

Comment: @Random832 $H(X)=\log_2n$ is a simplified formula for the entropy of a random variable $X$ which is uniformly distributed over $n$ possible values. In the general case (i.e. for non-uniform distributions), the formula is $H(X)=-\sum_{x\in A}(\log_2\Pr[X=x])\cdot\Pr[X=x]$, from which the complicated expression for $\log_26$ can be obtained.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> On the other hand, the Shannon entropy of a 6-sided die tossed 100 times is $-6 × 1/6 × \log_2(1/6) = 2.5849625007$ bits.

That is wrong: $-6\cdot\frac16\cdot\log_2\frac16$ is the entropy of a **single** die roll. Assuming the $100$ die rolls are independent, you can simply sum the entropies of the individual rolls to obtain
$$ 100 \cdot\left(-6 \cdot\frac16\cdot\log_2\frac16\right) \approx 258.49625 \text, $$
which is precisely $\log_2(6^{100})$ as expected.

Answer (score 12):

It seems that with your shannon entropy, you are using 100 tosses to estimate the shannon entropy of a **single** die toss. If it is a fair die, that would be $\log_2{6}\approx 2.58$.

This is different from rolling a die 100 times to generate a cryptographic key, for example. Each roll of the fair die would contain $2.58$ bits of entropy, so in total you would have approximately $2.58\cdot 100=258$ bits of entropy, or $\log_2{6^{100}}=\log_2(6)\cdot 100$ as mentioned in the comment.